Problem regarding evaluation of limits and its application in finding derivatives.
If I want to calculate the derivative (slope) of a function $f(x): \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=x^2$ at a point $x_0$,
$f'(x_0)$= $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{x^2-x_0^2}{x-x_0}$, where $x$ is never equal to $x_0$.
Step 1: here, we can cancel the factor $(x – x_0)$ as x is never equal to $x_0$ (but is very close to it as we want) so the factor is never equal to zero thereby allowing us to cancel it, so it gives us $(x + x_0)$ inside the limit.
Step 2: Now as x is as close to $x_0$ as we want it to be (but never equal to $x_0$), we can tell its limit is almost equal to $2x_0$, so the slope of the function is equal to $2x_0$.
Now my questions,
Q1.) Here in step 2, the limit seems to be an approximation, but if we look at how limit is defined (delta epsilon definition of limit), it cannot be an approximated in step 2, as it is a number which we can make a function very close to as we want, but if we do not take x as approximation and instead take it as equal to $x_0$ in step 2 thereby making the limit equal (and not approximately) to be $2x_0$ (because definition says limits are not approximations) then we have to imply the same in step 1 , now the problem here is that we could earlier cancel the factor $(x-x_0)$ as it was very close to zero but never equal to zero, but now from step 2 if we consider $x=x_0$ then the factor becomes zero and hence we cannot cancel it which leads to the limit not being solved. Why and how does this work?
Q2.) If we ignore question one for a second and assume the usual way, where we simplify and substitute the limits regardless of the above doubts(i.e. take limit as equal to $2x_0$ rather than taking it as approximation), then from the definition of limits we can say that the slope function which is not defined at $x_0$, has $2x_0$ as the limit, i.e. we can make the slope function as close to $2x_0$ as we want, but in any case the value of slope function (and therefore the slope value) is still not equal to $2x_0$ as its not defined at $x_0$.
So, in short how is:
Slope of the function (given by $\frac{(x^2 – x_0^2)}{(x - x_0)}$, where x is never equal to $x_0$) = the slope value
                              but also

= a number that can be made to differ from the slope function near $x_0$  by as little as we please(but never equal to it).
One might tell that, that is how slope is defined. If so, then why should slope be defined that way? Because when we know that limit is only a number which is not necessarily equal to the function value at the point, then why tell its equal to the value of actual slope, when its only a number that is not necessarily equal to the slope function (in this case the slope function which gives slope value at $x_0$ is not even defined at $x_0$)?
All of this seems to me that, we (or I) usually ignore the problems posed in question 1, that we calculate the limits by simplifying (simplifying assuming that x can never be $x_0$ as function is not defined there), but then in the end after we cancel the factors, we show our double standards and substitute $x=x_0$(ignoring that cancelling factors comes with the condition that x should not be $x_0$). If we don’t substitute x as $x_0$ but as a number very close to (approximately) $x_0$ which makes the limit approximately equal to $2x_0$ , we tell that the limit is not an approximation and is equal to $2x_0$ (from definition), which we then equate it to the value of slope at  $x_0$ (which is not what limit means as discussed in Q2 second part) while ignoring that the slope value is got form a slope function which is not even defined at the point, then how can we get the slope value for the  point from the slope function in the first place.(I only know that slope value exits as $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous and defined at $x_0$ )
Now, I know a way to calculate the value of slope of function without using the limits (called the method of normals given by Descartes) and it gives exact value of slope (at least in our case where $f(x)= x^2$) as the derivative gives. I know that the slope value from the normals method is correct as it is straight forward and does not involve any problems of assumption and does not pose the problems posed by limits in understanding. So, if I consider it to be correct then I have to consider the derivative to be correct too as they give the same slope value. So there has to be a mistake in my understanding of limits, or maybe it some how magically gives the answers regardless of the problems stated above. Please help. (I request answers with informal math as opposed to formal or rigorous math as its easier to understand, but if there is no other way, please do use rigorous math as I don’t want to compromise on genuinely understanding the answers for my questions)
Thank you in advance.

Use the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition of limits.
Let $\epsilon>0$
Then there exists a $\delta>0$ ($\delta=\epsilon$) such that for all $x$ satisfying $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$
The following is satisfied:
$|\frac{x^2-x_0^2}{x-x_0}-2x_0|<\epsilon$
Expand the absolute value:
$|\frac{x^2-x_0^2-2x_0 x+2x_0^2}{x-x_0}|=|\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{x-x_0}|$
Now since the $\delta$ neighborhood of $x_0$ is  a deleted neighborhood.
we can divide by $x-x_0$.
Thus:
$|\frac{x^2-x_0^2}{x-x_0}-2x_0|=|x-x_0|<\delta=\epsilon$
This is the formal rigorous proof.

What you've written as Step 1 and Step 2 is a colloquial interpretation of the limit. The epsilon-delta definition of limits is a formalisation of that colloquial approach.
When we write $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = L$, this is defined as meaning that for any positive value $\epsilon$, we can find a value $\delta$ such that $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. Or in other words when $x$ is within $\delta$ of $x_0$, the value of $f(x)$ is within $\epsilon$ of $L$ - that is, if you treat $L$ as being an "approximation" of $f(x)$, the error is less than $\epsilon$ as long as you're within $\delta$ of it.
Once we have the formal definition of a limit, there are a lot of important results that we can derive, and one of them is that if you have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ except possibly at $x = x_0$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} g(x)$, i.e. they have the same limit. Which importantly allows us to do things like cancel $\frac{x^2 - x_0^2}{x - x_0}$ down to $x + x_0$, because when $x \neq x_0$ the two functions are equal and so their limits are also equal.

now that i know limit can be treated as approximation ,my problem is how can we equate the slope value to the answer of the limit when the actual function used to find the slope value is not defined at the point? So it will be like telling that the slope value is approximately equal to 2$x_0$ as the limit value is not equal to the slope function value at the point ( but i know that the slope value is exactly equal to 2$x_0$ from the method of normals). Please help.

Plus why does it not matter that the function used to find slope is not defined at the required point(as this is what forces us to use limit which seems to give approximate answer)? My idea is that a function that does not have value at a point cannot give the answer for the point, so we dont use the function (but here we still use it by approximating )

The fact that the function is undefined at $x_0$ is the reason why we use limits. If it helps, imagine it as though we want to find the most natural choice of value to fill in the gap in the function - i.e. if we wanted to make it continuous, what value would go there? And that value is what the limit is.

Got it , thanks a lot for your help.
